# How to model and understand the asymmetry of a parallel RLC circuit spectrum

Tags: circuit-analysis, spectrum

I'm working with some parallel RCL circuits and I have noted that when I record a power spectrum (so \$\rm{dB}\$ vs \$\rm{Hz}\$) that the spectrum is asymmetric:

[image]

As I'm sure you all know if we calculate the impedance of a parallel RCL circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fibieM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

we get
$$ z_{\rm{RCL}} = \frac{i L R \omega}{R + i L \omega - C L R \omega^{2}} $$

and if we take the real-part of this then we get
$$ {\rm{Re}}\left(z_{\rm{RCL}} \right) = \frac{1}{R \left(\frac{1}{R^{2}} + \left( \frac{1}{L \omega} - C\omega \right)^{2} \right)}$$ 
which just by looking at we can tell is symmetric. But if we plot it:

[image]

So my first question is: **Where does this asymmetry come from?**

My first guess is that this is parasitic inductances and capacitances.

So my first question is: **how can I adjust my equation to consider these asymmetries so I can do better fits?**

My end goal is to extract the \$Q\$-factor and resonance frequency.

---

**Further research and comments**

Some additional comments since having an answer. The circuit proposed in the answer below is indeed a better fit, 
$${\rm{Re}}(Z) = \frac{R}{1 + C \omega^{2} (C R^{2} + L (C L \omega^{2} - 2))}$$
and is asymmetrical in the direction that is shown by my data. However there seems to be other components at work as the tilt in my data seems to be more extreme than is represented by the lineshape as described above.

[image]

In the graph above we can see the data, which I have linearised, add the lineshape as shown above. While the asymmetry is present (if I plot to large frequency spans) it seems to have a quite small sensitivity to frequency scaling, which makes me wonder if parasitic inductances and capacitances would adjust this.

Just for clarity here is the new lineshape showing the asymmetry better in logarithmic units:

[image]

Comment: You haven't demonstrated that your applied spectrum is flat. Neither have you shown how you apply the spectrum of noise to your filter.

Comment: @Andyaka What do you mean by flat?

Comment: Flat = equal power at all frequencies. Show your circuit too.

Comment: How would one demonstrate that? I'm happy to add the circuit, but I'm not sure what that adds? It's a parallel RCL circuit, or are you interested in how the excitation is applied?

Comment: LATEX tip: `\$` needs to be applied before and after formulae.

Comment: The question has no foundations without the spectrum being flat and knowledge of how you apply the signal. Surely that must be obvious?

Comment: The signal is simply the amplified Johnson-Nyquist noise of the circuit there is no external RF drive being applied.

Comment: @Q.P., Andyaka means that you can also include a graph with C and L disconnected.  You must also include the source resistance of the noise source in your equivalent circuit.   It might also be instructive to connect C and L separately and then show the spectrum.

Comment: Exactly - remove L and C and plot the noise.

Comment: Ahhhh, now I see. Unfortunately I can't. The RCL circuit is actually a shielded inductor, so a solenoid inside of a copper can essentially. The capacitance is parasitic coming from coil-to-coil and coil-to-shield interactions. The resistive component is emergent, so \$ R = \omega_{0} Q L\$

Comment: So, the "real" (noise producing) resistor is in series with the inductor and not parallel to the inductor, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The RCL circuit is actually a shielded inductor, so a solenoid inside
>   of a copper can essentially. The capacitance is parasitic coming from
>   coil-to-coil and coil-to-shield interactions.*

This means that the noise comes from the inductor's series resistance and therefore is not parallel to the inductor but in series: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCJiBG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the above (and below) I've made an estimate of the R, L and C values to roughly match the peak in the response at 29.6 MHz.

If so, then the 2nd order filter characteristic is low pass and not band pass such as shown with this [on-line simulator](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html): -

[image]

The red trace above is the response of a low pass 2nd-order filter and not a band-pass filter - might it look familiar?

Comment: It absolutely does! What's interesting is that this is in the same functional form as a Fano Resonance, I was using this as a parametrisation, but your model is preferential as it represents physics! Thanks!

Comment: I have no-idea what Fano resonance is but if it helps, that's good.

Comment: I have one final question if you are willing. If I add further orders, so additional inductances and capacitances in parallel would this affect the skew any further?

Comment: Yes it might - you could use the simulation tool I linked and, for two stages, you would half the resistance, half the inductance and double the capacitance to get equivalence in terms of frequency response.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Actually, it probably won't make the shape change at all because the Q factor would remain the same as well as Fc.

Comment: Hmmm. I ask because the lineshape is a much better fit, however the asymmetrical part is pulled further down, I tried adding a noise floor which scaled with frequency. I took a guess and added a \$ 1 /\sqrt{f}\$ scaling. Let me amend my question with a the plot.

Comment: @Q.P. Just make sure that it doesn't take anything away from the original question - add it under a title such as "edit section" or "further research information". I say this because someone coming along later might think I've not adequately answered you "fuller" question and might give me downvotes.

Comment: Okay I added a little more information.

Comment: @Q.P. the clean line-shape doesn't match why I suggested. It appears to match your original line-shape for a band-pass filter (which I believe you have ruled-out).

Comment: If I plot the new line shape to large frequency scales, then you see the asymmetry, however over the frequency range of the spectrum it seems its barely noticeable. I have added a plot of the new lineshape in log units and you can see the asymmetry better.

Comment: I think this is evolving into another question naturally. The original basic question has been addressed in that it is a low-pass response that shapes the noise and I'm losing track of what you are uncovering now.